# How to perform some operations on the Response object just before returning to calling API

Tags: java, spring, rest, aspect

I am writing a router in a project using which I am routing the API calls to different component. The issue is when the response is received and is getting returned from the current project, the current project adds some response headers like debug_id and server_link . Now I want to remove these headers without changing the existing code. Please guide me how to do this.

I have tried to find a solution and got a suggestion to try aspects. But I am confused. Do the aspects always run in the last? Won't I get in to a situation that aspects run first and code for adding headers runs after them. Is there a way to run a piece of code after all the processing has been done on the response and before the response is returned to the calling API.

Comment: sounds like task for http filter

Comment: Thanks Sir. I tried using filter and it solved my problem.